# C#: Udp socket and receivefrom() method

Tags: c#, udp

I want to have multiple server-like applications receiving data from the same UDP port. Each application would have two IP addresses and ports passed onto them corresponding to two different clients communicating with it.

Question: how does a UDP port handle data? If each application has two `beginreceivefrom()` methods to handle data, will it work like in this example by picking out data from the targetted IP addresses?

[Sketch of how I think it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjRu8.jpg)

Or do those `receivefrom()` methods have to wait for the oldest data received to be handled?
Is it possible to check if there is data waiting to be read from a certain IP? for example: `socket.dataFromThisIPEndPoint(ipep)`?

Edit: I've searched, and found that if i use socketoption REUSEADDR i can have multiple applications with a socket bind to the same ip and port, question:
Do i have to handle every message this port receives? or can i use beginreceivefrom and it will filter messages from other ip's? if this happens, will beginreceivefrom check for the oldest message that arrived, that might not have been handled and block the application until a message from an acceptable ip appears?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive data over multiple specific IPs then you should create one socket per IP. That way you can easily differentiate between IPs. You can bind to the same port on multiple IP addresses. Clients will send their packets to a specific combination of IP and port. This is how the server OS will decide which socket to forward that data to.

An entirely different design is to use just one IP and port but make the client say which application it wants to talk to inside of the packet data. You could prefix the data with a single byte that tells the type of request being made (e.g. `0 = request type A, 1 = request type B`). That way you need to deal with less network configuration.

Comment: This is all on the same ip and port:

Comment: This is all on the same ip and port:
tcp server on port 11000 would receive connections, once it receives two new connections it opens an application and passes two ip's to it. Sends a message over tcp to those 2 that it will close connection and closes.
Those two ip's will then send messages and receive to the same ip address, same port (11000) but now its over udp... 
One application communicating with every 2 new clients over udp (each application is a game room), sorry im a bit confused and my question remains the same, being poorly drawn on that sketch, can i do it like i've drawn?

Comment: or does every application have to receive every single message from every ip and analyse it to see if its meant for them or not? if that is the case, what is the purpose of receivefrom() method?

Comment: Each app decides what IPs it want to receive from. The OS will then only send the data meant for that IP. For each combination of IP and port there can only be one socket (and one application). No two apps can share the same socket. So each game room will need likely a new port. If you do that it can work.